# In node.js / Express why is a return statement sometimes needed after next() and sometimes not?

Tags: node.js, express

In the following test code `req.query` is checked to see if its value is name=cat.  If this is not true `next()` fires off the next piece of middleware.  This is accomplished without including a `return` statement after `next()` and it works as expected.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.name != 'cat') {
        next();
    } 
    res.send('it was cat');
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('it was not cat');
});
```

However when I change `res.send` to `res.sendFile` in the second piece of middleware the behavior is completely different.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

After the change `res.send('it was cat');` in the first piece of middleware fires every time, regardless of the value of name.  In addition the second piece of middleware never fires.

This can easily be fixed by adding a `return` after `next()` in the first piece of middleware.  The behavior becomes predictable again.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.name != 'cat') {
        next();
        return;
    } 
    res.send('it was cat');
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Why does this happen with and without the `return` statement?  A `return` is needed when I use `res.sendFile` but not when I use `res.send`.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I don't understand the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is accomplished without including a `return` statement after `next()` and it works as expected.

No, it *looks* like it works as expected, but it doesn't. For instance, if you retrieve `/test` without query parameter, or with a query parameter that doesn't equal `name=cat`, Express will log an error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I cannot reproduce your second example; for me, it always returns "it was cat" (in the example without `return`).

The common rule for any Express handler/middleware is: it should *either* end the response itself (by calling `res.end`, `res.send`, `res.render`, `res.sendFile`, etc) *or* pass the request along using `next`. In your case, without `return`, you're doing both. The result of that will be, practically speaking, undefined.

Comment: Super interesting!  So to ensure that code works I should include a `return` statement after `next()` in every normal circumstance?  Would that be considered a no-brainer?

Comment: @DR01D there can be situations where you wouldn't directly want to return after calling `next`, but you should consider the request to be "out of your hands" at that point. In other words,  you passed it along for someone else to deal with it. However, those situations are quite specific, and typically I use `return next()` as a shortcut for `next(); return;` (the return value of a middleware/handler in Express is ignored, so it's just a convenient shortcut; it doesn't actually return a value).

Answer (score 2):

When your listener performs `res.send('it was not cat')` the entire processing of the request takes place without hitting the trampoline.  The `next()` call never completes until after `res.send('it was not cat')` finishes.  So by the time the code for `send('it was the cat')` is reached, the response is already sent.

But when your listener performs `res.sendFile()` the processing of the response is asynchronous.  The file has to be read into memory, which is non-blocking I/O in Node.  The callback for that I/O is placed into the event queue, and then processing continues.  So the `next()` call returns and then `send('it was the cat')` executes.  All this is before the file is even read into memory.  Later when the file is read, the code dutifully attempts to send the response, but it's too late.